# Why does Emacs use AppData for user's home directory on Windows?

Tags: user-home

In NT Emacs (Mingw64/MSYS2 distro):

```
-- for me returns: c:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming
(expand-file-name "~")
```

This is in consent with the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html

I understand that you need to place apps garbage to `AppData/Roaming`. But then I lose convenient `~/` prefix for other stuff. Like **I want to type `~/Downloads` instead of `c:/Users/user/Downloads`**. Actually, I don't care about `AppData/Roaming` directory at all... I care about `%USERPROFILE%\Videos` & `%USERPROFILE%\Documents`...

As a workaround I set `HOME` to `USERPROFILE`.

Another, but more cumbersome workaround: creating symlinks from `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\<DIR>` to `%USERPROFILE%\<DIR>` for each `<DIR>`.